# How to show an image with large dimensions across multiple pages in a PDF using iText5?

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation

I have a graph image with large dimensions which I need to display in a PDF file.

I can't scale to fit the image as this would make text on the node illegible.

How could I split the image into multiple pages while retaining its original dimensions?

Comment: You might want to look at the sample [Hero2](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=101) which displays a large template split over many pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at the [TiledImage](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/images/TiledImage) example. It takes an image at its original size and it tiles it over 4 pages: [tiled_image.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/tiled_image.pdf)

[image]

To make this work, I first asked the image for its size:

```
Image image = Image.getInstance(IMAGE);
float width = image.getScaledWidth();
float height = image.getScaledHeight();
```

To make sure each page is as big as one fourth of the page, I define this rectangle:

```
Rectangle page = new Rectangle(width / 2, height / 2);
```

I use this rectangle when creating the `Document` instance and I add the same image 4 times using different coordinates:

```
Document document = new Document(page);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
document.open();
PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContentUnder();
canvas.addImage(image, width, 0, 0, height, 0, -height / 2);
document.newPage();
canvas.addImage(image, width, 0, 0, height, 0, 0);
document.newPage();
canvas.addImage(image, width, 0, 0, height, -width / 2, - height / 2);
document.newPage();
canvas.addImage(image, width, 0, 0, height, -width / 2, 0);
document.close();
```

Now I have distributed the image over different pages, which is exactly what you are trying to achieve ;-)

Comment: With your solution the image is getting cut from right and side and coming in the last page. Also can you please tell me the solution for the dynamic pages?