# How to split SVG into chunks of desired size to render it to PDF

Tags: svg, pdf-generation, itext, aspose.pdf

I want to render a large SVG image to a PDF document (PageSize = A4).I am using Itext Library and Java. Here is a post that describes how to render a image larger than page size to PDF () [How to show an image with large dimensions across multiple pages in ITextPdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26859473/how-to-show-an-image-with-large-dimensions-across-multiple-pages-in-itextpdf). But when I use this way of rendering I have 2 problems.

[image]

1)The Image ignores the page boundaries.

2)Some time the SVG splits in a way which cuts the text written in the SVG.

Both the problems can be solved If I can control the height of SVG to be rendered on each page, but I cannot find any way to control both Height, and starting point of a Image while rendering it to PDF.

Comment: can this be solved with aspose library?

Comment: Use the SVG viewBox to control exactly what you want to show.

Comment: @KevinBrown. I want to show complete SVG but Chunk by Chunk. changing viewbox will require changing XML again and then parsing it again.

Comment: If you were using something like an XML+XSL solution and you know the various viewBox coordinates you could easily implement to chunk the SVG for each page by adding the viewBox into the SVG dynamically on processing.